# The inverse of a locally integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f\neq 0$ is a locally integrable function, then can we say the same thing for $\dfrac{1}{f}$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0 is locally integrable

Comment: presumably your question should assume that $0$ is assumed as a value only on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: thanks, of course $f\neq 0$

Comment: $x^2$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia page "[Locally integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function)" in the examples section gives you some non locally integrable functions.

Specifically $g(x)=\frac 1x$ is integrable on any compact subset of $(0,1)$ but not on $[0,1]$.

The example given forces $g$ to be defined in $0$ with $g(0)=0$, now since zero is in the domain of definition, we can take compacts $[0,\epsilon]$ or $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and the integral is divergent.

For our problem we want $f$ and $g=\frac 1f$ to be defined so we can modify this example to:
$$
\begin{cases}f(x)=x & x\neq 0\\
\\
\\
f(0)=1\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}\dfrac 1f(x)=\dfrac1x&x\neq 0\\
\dfrac 1f(0)=1\end{cases}
$$
$f$ is locally integrable (the discontinuity in $0$ is not an issue) but $\frac 1f$ is not because it is divergent on compacts that contains $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much